# Maven: Trouble deploying third party JAR to a remote repository

Tags: maven-2, maven

I'm using Maven 3.  I'm trying to deploy a third party artifact to a remote repository but am getting a strange error.  The command I'm using to deploy is

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.myco.util.ant \
  -DartifactId=selenium-ant-task \
  -Dversion=1.4 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=/Users/davea/.m2/repository/com/myco/util/ant/selenium-ant-task/1.4/selenium-ant-task-1.4.jar \
  -DrepositoryId=sonatype-nexus \
  -Durl=http://sonatype.myco.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases
```

And the error I get when I run this command is

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file (default-cli) on project maven-selenium-plugin: The parameters 'url' for goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy-file are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

What's going on here?  I have defined my repositoryId, "ssonatype-nexus" in my ~/.m2/settings.xml file and verified the credentials in there are correct.

Thanks for any help, - Dave

Comment: `Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.` Could help you fixing your error :)

Answer (score 3):

`deploy:deploy-file` is not intended to be run in a directory with a pom.xml file - you should run it somewhere else. If you want a specific POM uploaded with it, don't forget the `-DpomFile` argument as the default is to generate a basic one.

However, I notice that you're deploying a file from the local repository - if this was placed there by a Maven build you are certainly better to have that project do the deployment, using the `<distributionManagement>` element and `deploy` lifecycle phase.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your url is formatted incorrectly.

Try:

-Durl=file://path_to_m2_repo

[See here for more](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html).

Edit: Note, the URL is for the local repo in this case. Maven should deploy to a Nexus based on the POM and -DrepositoryId.

Comment: The URL formatting is correct - despite what the usage guides use as examples, you don't need to deploy to a file location (which would still be considered a remote repo, even if it is hosted on a file system).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what you're suggesting.  I changed my URL to be "-Durl=file:///path/to/jar/I/want/to/deploy" but I still got the error.  Could you give an example using the path to the file I want to deploy and the repository id?

Comment: From what I understand from that doc is that the Durl should be the path to your local repository( or where the file resides), not to the file you want to deploy, that's what -Dfile is for. The -DrepositoryID should match the ID you specify in <distributionManagement> located in the POM file. I would assume this would push the given Dfile to your m2 repo (Durl) and deploy it to the DrepositoryID defined in the POM, in this case your Nexus. If that doesn't work, I'd like to see your <distributionManagement> attributes from your POM.

Comment: Something like (plus any other tags you want): mvn deploy:deploy-file 
  -DgroupId=com.myco.util.ant \
  -DartifactId=selenium-ant-task \
  -Dversion=1.4 \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dfile=selenium-ant-task-1.4.jar \
  -DrepositoryId=sonatype-nexus \
  -Durl=c:/Users/davea/.m2/repository/com/myco/util/ant/selenium-ant-task/1.4/  Then just make sure that your maven settings.xml is set-up to authorize a user to the nexus, and that the user has access to deploy to it.